# remove plymouth login screen (and leave MATE in place)

Tags: mate, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10, with MATE desktop environment installed.

When my laptop wakes from hibernation (by opening the lid), I see the MATE login screen for a bit.  Even if I type my password in there, the system then switches to a screen with a black background (and bubbles!) that I think is the plymouth login screen.

How can I get rid of that other screen, and just leave MATE in place?

Results of `dpkg -l | grep -Ei "plymouth|light-locker|xscreensaver|screensaver|lightdm|slick"` :

```
ii  cinnamon-screensaver                          4.6.0-2ubuntu0.1                     amd64        Cinnamon screen saver and locker
ii  libcscreensaver0:amd64                        4.6.0-2ubuntu0.1                     amd64        library and introspection data used by cinnamon-screensaver
ii  liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64                  1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1                    amd64        LightDM GObject client library
ii  libplymouth4:amd64                            0.9.4git20190712-0ubuntu4.1          amd64        graphical boot animation and logger - shared libraries
ii  libplymouth5:amd64                            0.9.5-0ubuntu2.1                     amd64        graphical boot animation and logger - shared libraries
ii  light-locker                                  1.8.0-1ubuntu1                       amd64        simple screen locker for lightDM display manager
ii  light-locker-settings                         1.5.0-0ubuntu4                       all          simple configuration tool for light-locker
ii  lightdm                                       1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1                    amd64        Display Manager
ii  mate-screensaver                              1.24.1-1                             amd64        MATE screen saver and locker
ii  mate-screensaver-common                       1.24.1-1                             all          MATE screen saver and locker (common files)
ii  plymouth                                      0.9.5-0ubuntu2.1                     amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer
ii  plymouth-label                                0.9.5-0ubuntu2.1                     amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - label control
ii  plymouth-theme-spinner                        0.9.5-0ubuntu2.1                     amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - spinner theme
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo                    0.9.5-0ubuntu2.1                     amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - ubuntu theme
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text                    0.9.5-0ubuntu2.1                     amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - ubuntu text theme
rc  xscreensaver                                  5.36-1ubuntu1                        amd64        Screensaver daemon and frontend for X11
```

And yes, I would like to continue using MATE as my desktop environment.

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported to Launchpad …

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -Ei "plymouth|light-locker|xscreensaver|screensaver|lightdm|slick"` to the question to get details about your system. Do you plan to save MATE on this system?